# wxPython: When selecting a row on frame1 the same row is selected on frame2

Tags: python, wxpython

I've a code that extracts some minimalist data using API and when double clicking on a cell it opens a new frame with more detailed data about that row. I also select the complete row when a cell is clicked.

My problem is that when I select a row on the second frame it is also selected on the first frame. Also, when I try to select row #10, for example, on the second frame and the first frame contains less rows, the row won't select and I receive an error message saying that the row doesn't exist.

Is there a way to differentiate between the 2 frames? I tried renaming the second frame TestFrame1 but that doesn't change anything.

Here is the code of the first frame, the second one is based on the same template with the only difference TestFrame1 instead of TestFrame.

```
class SimpleGrid(gridlib.Grid): 
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)


        # test all the events
        self.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_SELECT_CELL, self.OnSelectCell)

    #Select complete row
    def OnSelectCell(self, evt): 
         self.log.write("OnSelectCell: (%d,%d) %s\n" % 
                        (evt.GetRow(), evt.GetCol(), evt.GetPosition())) 
         self.SelectRow(evt.GetRow()) 
         evt.Skip() 

    #open TestFrame1
    def openPublishers(self, evt):

        from publishers import TestFrame1
        frame = TestFrame1(self, sys.stdout)
        frame.Show()

class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, 0, "Report", size=(1400,800))
        self.grid = SimpleGrid(self, log)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from wx.lib.mixins.inspection import InspectableApp
    app = InspectableApp(False)
    frame = TestFrame(None, sys.stdout)
    frame.Show(True)
    #import wx.lib.inspection
    #wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you,

Comment: You have 2 identical definitions called `openPublishers`

Comment: It's just a copy-paste error. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. So if someone have the same problem here is what I have done.

The first solution was to remove `evt.Skip() in OnSelectCell` because the events were propagating to the wrong parent windows. This solved the row selection, but I was still stuck with the issue where I can't select any row in the child frame that doesn't exist on the parent frame.

To fix this I had to be more specific when calling Bind. I passed the designated source widget in the 3rd parameter. This way the binding only match events coming from that widget. In other words:

```
    # instead of this
    self.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_CELL_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnCellLeftDClick)

    # I did this
    self.Bind(gridlib.EVT_GRID_CELL_LEFT_DCLICK, self.OnCellLeftDClick, self)
```